# Uploading image taken from gallery app (Quality issue)

Tags: android, http-post, uri

Using Android's gallery app to select a photo to upload with httppost later. The photo gets uploaded but it's **very low quality and size**. I have been reading about setting the `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG` will make it lossless but it's taking the photo from `2000x1500` to `250x187`.

Is it possible that I'm getting the thumbnail and not the actual image? I'm using Photos from Google.

**Code**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
    super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );

    if ( resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK ) {
        selectedImage = Uri.parse( data.getDataString() );

        try {   
            final Bitmap v = DecodeUriImage.Decode( selectedImage, getActivity() );
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            v.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao );
            byte[] byte_arr = bao.toByteArray();

            // Add image to array
            images.set( selectedImageIndex, Base64.encodeToString( byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT ) );

            } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG will compress the image but It depends on what kink of format you have used on the non-compressed image. You should use a vectorial image to get the best results because on the "compressing transfer" the immage loses the quality both in getting the image bigger on not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to put the selected image in a Bitmap for later use. Moreover you did not show what all is happening in `DecodeUriImage.Decode( selectedImage, getActivity() );`. Maybe it's quality is changed there. Instead realise you have a media path in `selectedImage` which you can convert to a real path to the filesystem. Save that path for later use.

If you use it later than just load the file in a byte array and encode base64. Do not use Bitmapfactory.